# PHP: Decoding Html Entities

Tags: php, html-entities

I want to decode html entities using php html_entity_decode() but my html entities seem incompatible with the function.

```
Example Input String: html_entity_decode('&amp;lt;strong&amp;gt;');
Outputs: &lt;strong&gt;
```

Removing the `'amp;'` solves the problem and produces `<strong>` but my file has `'amp;'` before every html entity. A mass removal of `amp;` would probably solve the problem, but also very destructive to the html. Is it possible to convert my entities with this situation of an extra `amp;` before all entities?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's double encoded - Run the string through [`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net/html_entity_decode) twice.

```
echo html_entity_decode( html_entity_decode('&amp;lt;strong&amp;gt;'));
```

This [will output](http://viper-7.com/of9gyV):

```
<strong>
```

Comment: Thanks your answer works perfect. My mistake not pasting in the ending semicolon. That was an insanely fast answer by the way!

Comment: @JMC - I am fast `:)` - Glad I could help!