# retrive html data from database in correct format when htmlspecialchars was used while inserting the data

Tags: php, mysql

hello i was trying to insert whole html data into database for which i used

```
$details = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['message'])));
```

which seem to work fine as before it was giving error as there were extra `""` while inserting the html for eg `"<p>hello</p>"` so by using the above it got inserted by now when i am trying to retrieve the data its not coming in correct format.

can some one point me what to use with `<?php echo $row['details']; ?>` to get the correct html format

Comment: And where did you find this method of preparing text for database insertion? It's very much exactly the wrong escaping function order. Look into prepared statements.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Decoding Html Entities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581555/php-decoding-html-entities) or better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6465263/reverse-htmlentities

Comment: Does the data have to be human readable while in the database? If not, I'd just `encode in base64` for storage, then `decode from base64` to display it.

Comment: no the data is not be readable to humans in database lol . but still is there any way to get it in correct format with the functions i used while inserting data into database

Comment: the suggested links does not give the the result :(

Comment: for eg i want this in normal html `rn&lt;p&gt;bnn &amp;nbsp;&lt;img src=&quot;/neeti/wedding%20website/admin/data/img/uploads/1280_Golf With Sun.jpg&quot; style=&quot;line-height: 1.5em; cursor: nw-resize; width: 257.6px; height: 161px;&quot;&gt;&lt;/p&gt;rn`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `stripslashes`. because `mysql_real_escape_string` put / before each quote `(" ')`. when you use stripslashes, it will remove that slashes. so you dont get proper output

Comment: this was really something useful. I removed `stripshlases` from the input of data and it worked like a charm thanks for saving me to be awake at late night :)